# Problem with startup script

Tags: debian, init.d

I am trying to get Chandler running on a debian box on startup under user 'chandler', and have tried the following script, locating it in init.d:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/chandler
#

RETVAL=$?
CHANDLER_HOME="/chandler"

# check input
case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl ];
      then
        /bin/su chandler $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl start
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    if [ -f $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl ];
      then
        /bin/su chandler $CHANDLER_HOME/bin/osafsrvctl stop
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/osafsrvctl {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

I then ran:

```
update-rc.d chandler defaults
```

I've checked that the startup scrip in init.d has 755 permissions...  but no joy.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for any pointers.

UPDATE: per the suggestions below, here is the init header I've added to the script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          chandler
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop chandler server
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Have you tried to run the script manually?

Comment: Running the above script from the command line as root (/etc/init.d/chandler start), it starts without error.

Comment: Did the `update-rc.d` script create all of the `/etc/rcX.d/*` symlinks correctly?

Comment: Yep, all symlinks are there, using the init info comment below as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at other scripts in `/etc/init.d` and you should see an LSB header comment block that looks similar to this example from `fetchmail`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          fetchmail
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      1
# Short-Description: init-Script for system wide fetchmail daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

This type of block is required.

From `man update-rc.d`:

> update-rc.d has two modes of operation for installing scripts into  the
>          boot  sequence.  A legacy mode where command line arguments are used to
>          decide the sequence and runlevel configuration, and  the  default  mode
>          where dependency and runlevel information in the init.d script LSB comment header is used instead.  Such header is required to be present  in
>          init.d  scripts.   See the insserv(8) manual page for details about the
>          LSB header format.

Comment: Done, confirmed all symlinks created K**chandler, S**chandler for each rc*.d directory.  Still doesn't come up on reboot.

Comment: @Paul: Please post the actual header as an edit to your question. Do you get anything in your logs?

Comment: OK, might have found the issue... the startup script, when run by the system vs a user, is complaining about missing env variable JAVA_HOME, which I had defined in /etc/profile...  sorry for such a basic question, but where should I be defining env variables that the system can use?

Comment: Got it figured out, exported JAVA_HOME from the chandler script.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pmmenneg: I would define them in, for example, `/etc/default/chandler` or `/etc/default/local` then source that in your script using `. /etc/default/chandler` or `. /etc/default/chandler`.

Comment: @Dennis: absolutely perfect, thank you for the suggestion!